# How can i create QML canvas in my C++ code and attach video on that? Such as Java Canvas i can

Tags: c++, qt, qml

How to create QML such canvas, and attach XOverlay video object on that canvas?

```
Java:
final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(); 
canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200)); 
XOverlay.wrap(video).setWindowID(canvas);

C++
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "qmlapplicationviewer.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QmlApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setOrientation(QmlApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationAuto);
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QLatin1String("qml/QmlTest1/main.qml"));

    // set the window no border, to do full screen live VIDEO
    viewer.setWindowFlags(
                            Qt::CustomizeWindowHint |
                            Qt::FramelessWindowHint
    );
    viewer.showExpanded();

    return app.exec();
}
```

My ref:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativeexamples.html

http://www.scriptol.com/programming/qml.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video playback in QML can be done through Qt Mobility's Video element:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/qml-video.html

Comment: link is broken, also did this ever answer the original question of drawing a video to a QtCanvas?